# invalidate JWT token server side

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, npm, jwt

I'm working on my web application using Node JS and Express JS. I'm using JWT for auth token. When user logout, I remove client side token but I need to remove also server side token. I use express-jwt-blacklist but something doesn't work.

```
app.post('/logout', auth.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    blacklist.revoke(token);
    res.json({ "status" : "200"})

});
```

and this is express-jwt-blaklist configuration:

```
blacklist.configure({
  tokenId: 'jti',
  strict: true,
  store: {
    type: 'memcached',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '11211',
    keyPrefix: 'mywebapp:',
    options: {
      timeout: 1000
    }
  }
});
```

This is function that checks if token is valid or not.

```
var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {

    if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== "undefined") {
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        let privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/private.pem', 'utf8');

        jwt.verify(token, privateKey, { algorithm: "HS256" }, (err, user) => {
            
            if (err) 
                res.render('loginPage.ejs');

            else
                return next();

        });
    } else 
        res.render('loginPage.ejs');
}
```

If I try to log out without removing the client-side token, the token cannot be invalidated. Reading https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-blacklist doc I don't understand some things, like blacklist configuration and blacklist.remoke input.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Why are you even using jwt, wouldn't it be much easier to just use opaque tokens and store session data in memcached? https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/

Comment: At this point I cannot change the authentication method but I can only correct. I think using other solutions, such as expression session, may be a better solution for future applications